# How to run makefile projects on clion

Tags: c++, debugging, cmake, makefile, clion

If I have a C++ project which uses a makefile to run the code (via the terminal), how can I make a simple to run/debug(!) project in clion? Up to this point I have been using VSCode, but it seems that the Clion interface is much more intuitive (especially coming from pycharm and intellij). But I am having trouble understanding what should I put in the configurations of the project. I am open to changing it to cmake, but I have no idea how to do that too (other than opening a c++ executable new project and copying all contents of my main project).
Really confused here, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are we talking "normal" executable or is this an embedded project?

Comment: I have a "main" function which I would like to run by clicking the run button or debug. I have several doctest files that I would like to be able to run and debug. (in pycharm and intellij for example there is a green run debug icon on the left of the line number of anything runnable). Ideally I would like the same

Comment: What else than an _"executable project"_ would you expect to choose?

Comment: The way you phrased that makes me think, you will probably want to simply create a new CMake project and then just copy over all files. IMO thats the simplest way from a Makefile project to the "out-of-the-box CLion experience".

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I understand they are talking about importing a Makefile project vs. creating a new CMake executable project and importing all sources.

Comment: But it seems to be almost stupid to copy out the whole project into a new one just for the sake of running the code, isnt it? is there no "proper" way to do it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If I were starting a project from scratch and with no obligation to a makefile, then sure an executable project is the way to go, but its not my case. I have a school project, some of the files of which (including a makefile) are given to me and I am to add several other files/classes/tests to them.

Comment: Well in that case - have you tried simply opening the project folder (containing the Makefile file) in CLion? Usually that should let you configure it as a Makefile project.

Comment: @PhilMasteG I have tried, with no apparent result. Is there a step by step or a tutorial or can you give me some direction as to how to do it? and does it give the run/debug capabilities? thanks for the answers by the way

Comment: How to do this manually I mean

Comment: I'm not usually using Makefile projects with CLion. But usually there are plenty tutorials from JetBrains. Have a google for CLion Makefiles Import.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245345/discussion-between-appeldaniel-and-philmasteg).